# How can I make the width of a canvas tag as large as the half of the window?

Tags: html, css

I make a line diagram that reflects the course of the temperatures. I have created a grid and have set the height of a canvas tag. I can't do the width like this. How can I set the width to be exactly half the width of the window?

My attempts:

```
width: 50%;
```

then it has a width of 50px.

```
width: window.innerWidth / 2;
```

gives an error

```
column-fill: auto;
```

doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```css
width: 50vw;
```

This should set the width of the element to 50% of the window width (view-width).

Answer (score 0):

You can use css decorators:

```
<style>
   @media  {
#can {
    width:50%;
    }
}
</style>
<canvas id ='can'></canvas>
```

check this link for more: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

By the way, the width will always be 50% of the box containing it, so if you put it inside a div or anything else be sure to adjust them